# Server to ask Ember app to display one of its route while passing model data

Tags: ember.js, express

My understanding is that if a given route in an Ember app needs to grab data from the server to feed its model, we will either use Ember data with a RESTful API or just an AJAX request, and the request for model data will come from the Ember app to the server.

But what if I want the server itself, at the end of a server-side process, to ask the Ember app to display one of its routes by passing to it some data to be used as the route model?

Basically, a process on the Node-based server (with Express) ends up like so:

```
function(req,res) {
    res.redirect("/#/someEmberAppRoute");
}
```

The req parameter carries some object that I want to pass to the Ember route in order to be used as a model for that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up solving this problem was to store on the server the output of the server-side process and have the Ember route someEmberAppRoute's model send a GET request to the server to grab that output and feed its model, instead of trying to push it directly from the server to the client.